# scanpy neighbors function: LLVM ERROR: Symbol not found: __svml_sqrtf8

Tags: python, llvm, numba, scanpy

Whenever I use `sc.pp.neighbors(adata)` I get this message (without any error):

[image]

I have:

`scanpy==1.8.1`

`pynndescent==0.5.4`

`numba==0.54.0`

`umap-learn==0.5.1`

`anndata==0.7.6`

My dataset contains only ~20,000 cells so it's quite weird that my kernel dies using this relatively small dataset.

I even tried to use scanpy's `bbknn` function as an alternative, and my kernel died as well.

I also encountered the same problem as an issue on github: https://github.com/theislab/scanpy/issues/1567 but it had no solution yet.

I tried to run the code on cmd instead of jupyter-notebook and got the next error:

`LLVM ERROR: Symbol not found: __svml_sqrtf8`

What should I do in order to properly run this function?

Comment: If you can reproduce the problem outside the Jupyter Notebook, then it's not really a problem relative to the use of Jupyter, and that tag can be avoided.  The problem is somewhere else.  The issue is likely related to numba, and possibly an incompatibility between a pre-compiled numba and other libraries installed on your system.  I wonder if it would help if you set the environment variable `NUMBA_DISABLE_INTEL_SVML=1`

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I tried to use your idea but unfortunately setting the environment variable didn't work as well. I typed exactly what you suggested and the kernel still died. I got the same error again on cmd as well

Answer (score 0):

The above [comment by @Iguananaut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69026039/scanpy-neighbors-function-llvm-error-symbol-not-found-svml-sqrtf8/70452493#comment122001188_69026039) worked for me:

> If you can reproduce the problem outside the Jupyter Notebook, then it's not really a problem relative to the use of Jupyter, and that tag can be avoided. The problem is somewhere else. The issue is likely related to numba, and possibly an incompatibility between a pre-compiled numba and other libraries installed on your system. I wonder if it would help if you set the environment variable `NUMBA_DISABLE_INTEL_SVML=1`

I created a new environmental variable as below:

- variable name: `NUMBA_DISABLE_INTEL_SVML`
- variable value: `1`

This then allowed me to run `umap`. Before I was seeing the same error in a terminal window:

```
Symbol not found: _svml_sqrtf8
```

Answer (score 0):

Had to uninstall and reinstall soundfile and librosa after changing hardware and migrating from intel to nvidia GPU.  I loved my intel GPU but somebody else is using it now :)